# How to populate pool with different types of sprites in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, pool

I am new to Android AndEngine game development. I am developing a game in which i am using GenericPool to load multiple spites on the screen. Problem is that these sprites are of same type.I want to load different type of sprites. After some research i got the idea of using Multipool but do n't know how to use it in my code.

Here is my code :

```
public class Enemy {
public Sprite sprite;
public int hp;
// the max health for each enemy
protected final int MAX_HEALTH = 2;
Camera mCamera;
BaseActivity activity = BaseActivity.getSharedInstance();

public Enemy() {

    sprite = new Sprite(32, 32, BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().mBirdTextureRegion,
            BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    init();
}

// method for initializing the Enemy object , used by the constructor and
// the EnemyPool class
public void init() {
    hp = MAX_HEALTH;

     mCamera = activity.mCamera;

}

public void clean() {
    sprite.clearEntityModifiers();
    sprite.clearUpdateHandlers();
}

// method for applying hit and checking if enemy died or not
// returns false if enemy died
public boolean gotHit() {
    synchronized (this) {
        hp--;
        if (hp <= 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}


public class EnemyLayer extends Entity {

private LinkedList<Enemy> enemies;
public static EnemyLayer instance;
public int enemyCount;

public static EnemyLayer getSharedInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static boolean isEmpty() {
    if (instance.enemies.size() == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static Iterator<Enemy> getIterator() {
    return instance.enemies.iterator();
}

public void purge() {

    detachChildren();
    for (Enemy e : enemies) {
        EnemyPool.sharedEnemyPool().recyclePoolItem(e);
    }
    enemies.clear();
}

public EnemyLayer(int x) {
    enemies = new LinkedList<Enemy>();
    instance = this;
    enemyCount = 4;
}

public void restart() {
    Log.v("jimvaders", "EnemyLayer restarted");
    enemies.clear();
    clearEntityModifiers();
    clearUpdateHandlers();

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) {
        Enemy e = EnemyPool.sharedEnemyPool().obtainPoolItem();

        float finalPosX = (i % 6) * 2 * e.sprite.getWidth()/2 * 3/2;
        float finalPosY = ((int) (i / 6)) * e.sprite.getHeight() * 2;

        Random r = new Random();
        e.sprite.setPosition(r.nextInt(2) == 0 ? -e.sprite.getWidth() * 3
                : BaseActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH + e.sprite.getWidth() * 3,
                (r.nextInt(5) + 1) * e.sprite.getHeight());
        e.sprite.setVisible(true);

        attachChild(e.sprite);
        e.sprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(1,
                e.sprite.getX(), finalPosX, e.sprite.getY(), finalPosY));

        enemies.add(e);
    }
    setVisible(true);
    setPosition(50, 30);

    MoveXModifier movRight = new MoveXModifier(1, 50, 120);
    MoveXModifier movLeft = new MoveXModifier(1, 120, 50);
    MoveYModifier moveDown = new MoveYModifier(1, 30, 100);
    MoveYModifier moveUp = new MoveYModifier(1, 100, 30);

    registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(
            new SequenceEntityModifier(movRight, moveDown, movLeft, moveUp)));

}

public static void purgeAndRestart() {
    Log.v("Birds Shooter", "EnemyLayer PurgeAndRestart()");
    instance.purge();
    instance.restart();
}

@Override
public void onDetached() {
    purge();
    clearUpdateHandlers();
    super.onDetached();
}


public class EnemyPool extends GenericPool<Enemy> {

public static EnemyPool instance;

public static EnemyPool sharedEnemyPool() {

    if (instance == null)
        instance = new EnemyPool();
    return instance;

}

private EnemyPool() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected Enemy onAllocatePoolItem() {
    return new Enemy();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleObtainItem(Enemy pItem) {
    pItem.init();
}

protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Enemy e) {
    e.sprite.setVisible(false);
    e.sprite.detachSelf();
    e.clean();

}
```

}

How can i modify  this code to use multiple sprites of different types intead of same type.????? Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Sprite class and make new pools using the custom Sprite Object. For example:

```
public class FlyingEnemy extends Sprite
{
//Class Body Here
}
```

Once you have overwritten the Sprite class to match your needs you simply extend the generic pool to handle your new Sprites

```
public class FlyingEnemyPool extends GenericPool<FlyingEnemy>
{
//Class Body Here
}
```

Then you just use your new pools like normal.